# Window functions in view called with "where" gives bad execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view that uses LAG.

```
CREATE VIEW V_ImportedReadingDay2
AS
SELECT
    ID,
    PlacementID,
    LAG(Reading, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY MeterNumber ORDER BY Date) AS Val
FROM dbo.ImportedReadingDay
```

If I call it using "WHERE" it gets an execution plan much worse than if just calling the query.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    PlacementID,
    LAG(Reading, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY MeterNumber ORDER BY Date) AS Val
FROM dbo.ImportedReadingDay
WHERE (PlacementID = 12404)

SELECT *
FROM V_ImportedReadingDay2
WHERE (PlacementID = 12404)
```

[image]

This is a known problem. You can google the problem.
I have found two solutions. Either use a table valued function or move the LAG outside of the view.

**BUT I'd like to know if there are any other solutions since none of these work for me since I have to use the view in a client software.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two queries aren't logically the same. So, of course, they don't get the same execution plan.

Consider these queries:

```
select name,LAG(column_id) OVER (ORDER BY system_type_id) as cid
from sys.columns
where name='name'

select * from (
select name,LAG(column_id) OVER (ORDER BY system_type_id) as cid
from sys.columns
) t
where name='name'
```

Because of the logical processing order of queries, the `WHERE` clause is processed before the `SELECT` clause. So, for the first query, we *first* filter the `sys.columns` table to only retrieve rows with a particular name, and *then* we apply the `LAG()` function just on this filtered set (so, the lagged value will definitely come from another row which matches the filter).

For the second query, we first (logically) process the subquery. We're performing the `LAG()` function across the whole set of rows (because the subquery doesn't have any filters/`WHERE` clause) and then (in the outer query) we're filtering the set of rows. Importantly, that means that the lagged value may have been pulled from a row which doesn't match the final filter.

Well, when you use a view, it's similar to my second query. The value of `Val` retrieved when you use your view is *not* guaranteed to be from a row with a `PlacementID` equal to `12404`.

Comment: I know, as I mentioned they are simplifed.

Comment: The same analysis still applies - in the direct query against the table case, logically you *filter* and *then* `LAG`, and in the view query, you're `LAG`ing before you filter. They're still, logically, different queries.

Comment: Well yes the LAG was supposed to be able to fetch from a row not matching the same filter since the value belongs to a meter that could have been moved from one placement to another without resetting the Reading value. Though I realized that even if a LAG value could correctly belong to a previous placement it wasn't useful. So yes, you are correct that they are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

This was a simplified view just for this example.
In the real one I partition the LAG.
I found out that partitioning the LAG with the same as used in the "WHERE" (in this case PlacementID) solved the performance issue.